# Servlet : try to read pdf file using servlet in eclipse

Tags: java

i am try to read the file using ServletContext `

```
InputStream is = servletContext.getResourceAsStream(path)
```

the value of path is :

```
path = D:\Assignments\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\HelpGuide\GeneratedReports\userDetail.pdf`
```

the `userDetail.pdf` file is exist in given path , but when i try to get the resource as stream using servlet context define as above , the value of `is` is null .

Answer (score 1):

This is because the getResourceAsStream looks to a path relative to the context root. 
Checkout javadoc of servlet context and especially the "getResource" part: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)
You should use a relative path and put your pdf in your classpath, that would be a better practice as your app will not rely on an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

This is such a bad idea, as the servlet is telling you.

Put that PDF in the CLASSPATH (e.g. WEB-INF/classes of your WAR) and read it as an InputStream from the servlet context.

Absolute paths are the wrong way to go for web apps.

Comment: but this is eclipse ide , if i place the file in WEB-INF , then what is the file path ?

Comment: See my answer, but that is why you should use relative path and not absolute path.

Comment: the absolute file path is get from `getServletContext().getRealPath("fileName"))` method.

Comment: sir , how to deal with eclipse, in eclipse there is no classes folder in WEB-INF?

Comment: Yes there is.  Where do you think your serlvet .class file is compiled to?  Create one that you can see and put your PDF there.

Comment: If you are using maven you can put your pdf in the "src/main/resources" folder and it will be "compiled" (more precisely copied) into the WEB-INF/classes directory on your web app server. Do not forget to add the directory to the list of deployment inclusion in the application deployment on server configuration of Eclipse.

Comment: i place the file , where .class files are generated but , the `FileNotFoundException` throw.

Comment: if you do so you cannot use the getRealPath you mentioned above. As the path for getResourceAsStream is "relative".

Comment: @benzonico - why on earth would you advise someone who has such a poor understanding of Java to use Maven?  That's madness.

Comment: when  try to create the file using eclipse , it will return false . why?

Comment: @duffymo LOL! note that i did not advice to, but mention that if you use it... :)